# domain with www does not work for Caddy server

Tags: reverse-proxy, caddy

I'm using Caddy as a reverse proxy server that points to a docker container that runs web service at port 8181. The domain `abc.com` works, but `www.abc.com` does not work. I wonder where might be wrong:

**Caddyfile:**

```
abc.com {
    proxy / localhost:8181
}
```

I have an A record for `www.abc.com` that points to the IP address of the server.

Comment: It's good that you have your DNS set up correctly first. Just make your first line this: `abc.com, www.abc.com {`

Answer (score 0):

Caddy file should be

```
www.abc.com {
    proxy / localhost:8181
}
```